# Putting composer.json in the root of a CakePHP installation

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

My current website installation looks like this:

`.htaccess
app/composer.phar
app/composer.json
app/Config
app/Controller
app/Model
app/Plugin
app/Test
app/tmp
app/Vendor (CakePHP and most other composer packages get installed here)
app/webroot`

I would quite like the composer files to be in the root of the structure. I know I can change `vendor-dir` in `composer.json` to `app/Vendor` however the issue I am having is that some of my required packages are of the `cakephp-plugin` so they automatically get installed to the `Plugin` folder - this is working fine for the above folder structure. But if I move composer.json to the root, I am unsure how to make them go to `app/Plugin` without defining the path for each package in `composer.json` to override where composer would want to install to. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add this to your composer.json. I haven't tested it.

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "app/Plugin/{$name}/": ["type:cakephp-plugin"]
        }
    }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/composer/installers#custom-install-paths